# Cant display the LBP image after using exposed elbp function in python

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I am trying to display an lbp image after applying elbp function to a gray-scale image, the function  was exposed manually in the face module for python.
here's the code:

```
LBP = cv2.face.elbp(gray_roi,1,8)
cv2.imshow("Face",LBP)
```

But however, what I got is a pure black window,also I noticed that the cols and rows are always smaller than the original image by 2，here is the error information:

> could not broadcast input array from shape (95,95) into shape (97,97)

I noticed one other ppl asked the same question but was using c++ instead: [Unable to display image after applying LBPH (elbp()) operator in opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184358/unable-to-display-image-after-applying-lbph-elbp-operator-in-opencv)
But what I cant understand is what he meant by normalized the image to fit the screen rendering range?

here is the matrix ouput of my image:

[print(LBP)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XtUT.png)

As you can see, the pixel intensity distribution is normal.

here is the actual [elbp function](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/face/src/lbph_faces.cpp)!

Comment: Sorry this was my 1st time to ask a question, wasn't sure about the format :(

Comment: Is weird that a python function would do that, but maybe it is storing the values in the [0-1] interval internally, try to multiply your image for 255 and see if it is still black

Comment: I tried to use cv2.normalize(LBP1,LBP1,0,255,cv2.NORM_MINMAX) ,but the result is still the same :(

Comment: And you still got nothing? I really not sure then, you gonna have to dig into this elbp function documentation to see how exacly it behaves. Unless someone smarter than me knows this :)

Comment: really struggling here atm,but thanks for trying to help anyway!

Comment: My guess on the smaller size is: the LBP algorithm applies a mask, centered on an image pixel. Say the mask is 3x3 pixels size, on the edges of the source image, that mask can't be fully applied because 3 or 5 pixels are absent (off the side of the image), so it isn't applied at all - hence the array of LBP results has two fewer rows/columns - the top LH corner of the LBP output gives the results for the pixel one in from top LH corner of the original image. Obviously as you increase the mask size by specifying larger radius, then the output LBP result matrix will be get smaller.

Comment: As you say that elbp() is an internal function, does it actually produce an "image" result? Assuming it is an image, have you tried printing some of the pixel values, see if they are non-zero? You might find the values are all close to zero, and are being displayed correctly as so nearly black that you can't tell them from black. Maybe multiplying all the pixels by 32 or 64 will increase the contrast? Just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

@barny thx for your detailed response , based on your solution, I times the  matrix by a value like 64, finally I got the image shown, but I'm not sure why do I have to times a value to get the proper visible image,shouldn't it be done in the original elbp function?
and also , the matrix element value become very large:

here is some part of the histogram that I printed out from the shown image(times a value by 64):

```
histogram=scipy.stats.itemfreq(LBP1)
print(histogram)[[    0  1726]
```

[histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bupDl.png)

If someone can explain to me why do I have to multiply such a big value that would be great!

ps:this is my 1st time ask on stack overflow, thx for everyone who tried to help !

Comment: Does the documentation say that elbp returns a visible image? Just because it returns an array of values nearly the same size as the source image doesn't mean anything - that's just the size of the LBP results. So I don't think it's surprising that you have to process the LBP results to be able to visualise them in a human-friendlier way.